# BMW E92 335i 2008 head gasket

Tags: head-gasket, 335i

I have e92 335i 2008. Recently I had a water leaking from the head gasket. A 
week after replacing the headgasket everything was fine until I opened the 
oil filler to see there's water in it. Now I'm thinking that the headgasket is not installed properly or the head itself has a crack or something. The garage 
told me that the head was already checked and it's in perfect condition and 
the headgasket is new and cannot be misinstalled. He is telling me that it could be the oil housing is leaking from inside, not the  oil filter housing gasket or the head gasket.

Can anyone explain what could it be?

Comment: There are so many things it could be, from improperly installed head gasket to another problem they missed. I suggest you take it back to the garage and have them correct it. If they had done the work properly, you would not have coolant in your oil.